# How do I centre a map on a location typed by user?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am making a weather app and a feature is that when the user searches for a location, they can see where it is on a map. How do I centre the map on the location? Example: Searches for San Francisco and map shows San Francisco. Do I need to somehow convert the name to coordinates and then get those as an input for the map or can this be done in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this recently, and this is how I solved it. First, I used the MapKit API to do the natural language query:

```
let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
request.naturalLanguageQuery = sender.stringValue
let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch(request: request)

searchRequest.start(completionHandler: { response, error in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.results = response.mapItems
        // Present the results...
    }
})
```

Then once an item is selected, you should be able to center the map using it:

```
if let circularRegion = mapItem.placemark.region as? CLCircularRegion {
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: circularRegion.center, latitudinalMeters: circularRegion.radius * 2, longitudinalMeters: circularRegion.radius * 2)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}
```

I'm sure you'll want to tune the centering behavior a bit.